# Is there a way to run an already-built python API from google cloud?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I built a functioning python API that runs from my local machine. I'd like to run this API from Google Cloud SDK, but after looking through the documentation and googling every variation of "run local python API from google cloud SDK" I had no luck finding anything that wouldn't involve me restructuring the script heavily. I have a hunch that "google run" or "API endpoint" might be what I'm looking for, but as a complete newbie to everything other than Firestore (which I would rather not convert my entire api into if I don't have to), I want to ask if there's a straightforward way to do this.

**tl;dr** The API runs successfully when I simply type "python apiscript.py" into local console, is there a way I can transfer it to Google Cloud without adjusting the script itself too much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, the easiest solution for portable app is to use Container. And to host the container in serverless mode, you can use [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy).

In the getting started guide, you have python example. The main task for you is to create a [Dockerfile](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#containerizing)

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD python apiscript.py
```

*I adapted the script to your description, and I assumed that you have a `requirements.txt` file for the dependencies.*

Now, build your container

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/<PROJECT_ID>/apiscript
```

*Replace the PROJECT_ID by your project ID, not the name of the project (even if sometimes it's the same, it's a common mistake for the newcomers)*

Deploy on Cloud Run

```
gcloud run deploy --region=us-central1 --image=gcr.io/<PROJECT_ID>/apiscript --allow-unauthenticated --platform=managed apiscript
```

*I assume that your API is served on the port 8080. else you need to add a `--port` parameter to override this.*

That should be enough

---

Here it's a getting started example, you can change the region, the security mode (here no security) the name and the project.

In addition, for this deployment, the Compute Engine default service account is used. You can use another service account if you want, but, in any cases, you need to grant the used service account the permission to access to the Firestore database.

Comment: At which step do you have this issue? the image name must be in lower case only and you can't use _ underscore

Comment: The underscore was the issue. Appreciate the help!